# how to insert value in a particular location in csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

Is it possible to write at a particular location in a CSV file using PHP?

I don't want to append data at the end of the CSV file. But I want to add data at the end of a row already having values in the CSV.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. Complete working code:

```
<?php
//A helping function to insert data at any position in array.
function array_insert($array, $pos, $val)
{
    $array2 = array_splice($array, $pos);
    $array[] = $val;
    $array = array_merge($array, $array2);

    return $array;
}

//What and where you want to insert
$DataToInsert = '11,Shamit,Male';
$PositionToInsert = 3;

//Full path & Name of the CSV File
$FileName = 'data.csv';

//Read the file and get is as a array of lines.
$arrLines = file($FileName);

//Insert data into this array.
$Result = array_insert($arrLines, $PositionToInsert, $DataToInsert);

//Convert result array to string.
$ResultStr = implode("\n", $Result);

//Write to the file.
file_put_contents($FileName, $ResultStr);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it s not possible to insert new data in the middle of a file, due to filesystem nature.
Only append at the end is possible.

So, the only solution is to make another file, write a beginning part of source, append a new value, and then append the rest of the source file. And finally rename a resulting file to original name.

Comment: Any other solution to this problem

Comment: @Ankur  I've added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Technically [Col. Shrapnel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465599/how-to-insert-value-in-a-particular-location-in-csv-file-using-php/3465622#3465622) is absolutely right.

Your problem is that you don't want to deal with all these file operations just to change some data. I agree with you. But you're looking for the solution in a wrong level. Put this problem in a higher level. Create a model that represents an entity in your CSV database. Modify the model's state and call its `save()` method. The method should be responsible to write your model's state in CSV format.

Still, you can use a CSV library that abstracts low level operations for you. For instance, [parsecsv-for-php](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/wiki/Examples) allows you to target a specific cell:

```
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->sort_by = 'id';
$csv->parse('data.csv');
# "4" is the value of the "id" column of the CSV row
$csv->data[4]['firstname'] = 'John';
$csv->save();
```