# PHP Locate line to alter in CSV using Variables

Tags: php, arrays, csv

### Greetings fellow coders.

I have a csv file (includes/sbk.php, ignore the extension, it is a csv) that i read and delete lines from.

A sample of that csv file is ...

```
    serial,lastid,url,short,other
    01,without last ID,#,no scheduled search,no search criteria
    02,without last ID,#,no scheduled search,no search criteria
    03,without last ID,#,no scheduled search,no search criteria
```

It's got about 50 lines. The 1st line is used to define titles in an array and the rest are read into an array having it lifted from 0 starting point to 1.

Reading the CSV is not a problem. I also use the following code to delete lines, identified by the id (first csv col):

```
    if (isset($_POST['button'.$sID.'del'])) { 
            /* cmd */               //  $delLastID $delUrl $delShort $delOther cleans house for 
            $lines = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/sbk.php');
            $words =         ($sbk.','.$delLastID.','.$delUrl.','.$delShort.','.$delOther);
            $result = '';
            foreach($lines as $line) {
                if(substr($line, 0, 2) == $sbk) {
                    $result .= $words."\n";
                } else {
                    $result .= $line;
                }
            }
            file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/sbk.php', $result);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">parent.location="tabs.php";</script>';     // return the user to tabs
        }
```

### Now to my problem..

In an other script i read thru the file and have a huge form for the user to choose stuff that with a "Save" button it tries to do the same as above to re-write the specific line with my variables.

```
//      $VarForSbkLastID it's $elID[1][0];
//      $VarForSbkUrl it's htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
        $carVarVariant      = ($allCarVars['variant']);
        $VarForSbkShort     = $carVarMake.' '.$carVarModel.' '.$carVarVariant.' '.$carVarPriceFrom.' '.$carVarPriceTo.' '.$carVarMileageFrom.' '.$carVarMileageTo.' '.$carVarRegFrom.' '.$carVarRegTo.' '.$carVarEngineSizeFrom.' '.$carVarEngineSizeTo.' '.$carVarEnginePowerFrom.' '.$carVarEnginePowerTo.' '.$carVarFuel.' '.$carVarColor.' '.$carVarRegion.' ';
        $VarForSbkOther     = $carVarCategory.' '.$carVarMake.' '.$carVarModel.' '.$carVarVariant.' '.$carVarPriceFrom.' '.$carVarPriceTo.' '.$carVarMileageFrom.' '.$carVarMileageTo.' '.$carVarRegFrom.' '.$carVarRegTo.' '.$carVarEngineSizeFrom.' '.$carVarEngineSizeTo.' '.$carVarEnginePowerFrom.' '.$carVarEnginePowerTo.' '.$carVarFuel.' '.$carVarGearbox.' '.$carVarDoors.' '.$carVarDriveType.' '.$carVarColor.' '.$carVarAirbags.' '.$carVarDamage.' '.$carVarEuroclass.' '.$carVarRegion.' ';

if (isset($_POST['buttonadd'])) { 
        $lines = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/sbk.php');
        $words = ($refid2.','.$elID[1][0].','.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']).','.$VarForSbkShort.','.$VarForSbkOther);
        $result = '';
        foreach($lines as $line) {
            if(substr($line, 0, 2) == $refid2) {
                $result .= $words."\n";
            } else {
                $result .= $line;
            }
        }
        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/sbk.php', $result);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">parent.location="tabs.php";</script>';     // return the user to tabs
    }
echo '<input type="submit" name="buttonadd" value="Save">';
```

Well.. i'm stuck, can't figure what i'm doing wrong there and it doesn't execute my commands after isset, like when cleaning a line..

Anybody?

P.S. for reading i use the following.. http://pastebin.com/69nfjKPM

Comment: please don't reply with comments like, use a database or similar, i'm on a work enviroment and all these are required for other uses, the csv is automaticaly parsed from other scripts, before i got here. :S

Comment: Is your isset called at all?
Try adding debug outputs (simple echos and var dumps) to simply debug your code and fi9nd out what branch is not reached.

Comment: Hm, nice of you to think that, i'll check the differencies when in & out the "isset". ah i'm like 4h trying to figure out "why"!!

Comment: maybe you needs some debug in your foreach if statements to see what your substring returns and what your $refid2 is?
like `echo 'refid2:'.$refid2.' / substr result = '.substr($line, 0, 2).';` in your foreach? That might lead you 8in the right direction.

Comment: $refid2 is the referer id that is parsed using an included script that takes the $ref gives $refid and then changes it to $refid2 with is "proper", it's a variable that i get from the url referer of the previous url, it does give out the proper number (e.g. 01 or 02 with the leading 0 on the <10), i've already tested that out.. that's why i'm substr'ing the the 02 (1st two) characters from the csv

Comment: i did not ask for that. I simply advised you to check what value the $refid2 has in that exact branch where you try to alter the csv file and what the substring command returns in that branch :D

Comment: it's not inside some kind of array, in that script it gets the variable and it stays static for that specific page. For example if the user selects the 2nd tab, the $refid2 gets to be "02" as a static variable.

Comment: thinking of using some arrays to do what i want there, different way of reading and writing.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3465692/3243761 what is your opinion @AndreschSerj ?

Comment: Refactoring and producing cleaner code is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the [parseCSV](https://github.com/jimeh/php-parsecsv) library and successfully manipulated specific lines of the csv file.

**Thank you for everything fellow coders!**

Comment: i had some problems cause my variables came with leading zeros for <10 but i did some "if" to get declare new variables for the csv save